# NullPointerException and SQLNonTransientConnectionException when refreshing webpage

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, thymeleaf

Im using Spring and Thymeleaf to display the count of how many users I have in my database, and the code looks like this

```
    public long countUsers() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Long userCount = 0L;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionPool.getConnectionPool().getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_USER_COUNT);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        userCount = resultSet.getLong("rowcount");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    } finally {
        closeResource.close(statement);
        closeResource.close(resultSet);
        closeResource.close(connection);
        ConnectionPool.getConnectionPool().releaseConnection(connection);
    }
    return userCount;
}
```

This works fine and I display it on the web page like "There are X total users", but when I refresh the page like three times in one second the count goes to 0 and it stops working. I get these messages

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

and

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.AutoCloseable.close()" because "resource" is null
```

Im using a controller to dish up where I want the count to go

```
    @GetMapping("/")
public String homepage(Model model) {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    model.addAttribute("userCount", userService.countUsers());
    return "index";
}
```

and the HTML looks like

```
  <div>
    <p>There are a total of <span th:text="${userCount}"></span> users created</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, you should be configuring your database inside your application configuration and then using `@Autowired` (or an equivalent) to inject a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: You might want to read up on [Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) (or [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) if you would like to use JPA instead of SQL directly).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I was closing the connection and then adding it back to the `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

When I stopped closing the connection and started just releasing it back to the `List`, it worked!

Thank you to the comments for helping me towards the right path.